# JavaScript String Replace with a tricky regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to work out what regular expression I would need to change this string

```
html = '<img style="width: 311px; height: 376px;" alt="test" src="/img/1268749322.jpg" />';
```

to this

```
html = '<img width="311" height="376" alt="test" src="/img/1268749322.jpg" />';
```

with the help of Javascript.replace.

This is my start:

```
html = html.replace(/ style="width:\?([0-9])px*"/g, "width=\"$1\"");
```

Can anyone help me?

THANKS

Comment: Try to do it over the DOM if possible. Regular expressions are not suitable for processing HTML.

Comment: are you trying to manipulate specific tag? or are you trying to manipulate all of the tags of the same kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = '<img style="width: 311px; height: 376px;" alt="test" src="/img/1268749322.jpg" />';
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = html;
var img = d.firstChild;
var width = parseInt(img.style.width, 10);
var height = parseInt(img.style.height, 10);
img.setAttribute("width", width);
img.setAttribute("height", height);
img.removeAttribute("style");

alert(d.innerHTML);
```

Of course, things get slightly easier if you don't start with a string ;-)

Comment: it's HTML-Code given from a WYSIWYG-Editor

Answer (score 2):

1. It's [generally considered a Bad Thing to do HTML parsing with RegExs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

   Why not edit the DOM from JavaScript?
2. I'm not an expert on CSS, but isn't using style a better idea than width/height attributes?
3. You forgot the whitespace after `:` (`\s*`). You don't want ? there since it will miss >1 space or a tab

Comment: @Juri - just in case it's not obvious, the link is to the blog of one of two founders of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo is right, you should use DOM.

But to your regex: What is `\?` (question mark) supposed to mean? I would insert `\s*` (any number of whitespaces) at that position.

Answer (score 0):

I can make it more elaborate if you wish, let me know how this works:

```
html = html.replace(/style=".*?width:\s?(\d+).*?height:\s?(\d+).*?"/g, "width=\"$1\" height=\"$2\"");
```

Edit: escaped qq

Comment: this is it, thanks!
html = html.replace(/ style=".*?width:\s?(\d+).*?height:\s?(\d+).*?"/g, " width=\"$1\" height=\"$2\"");

Comment: Thanks Juri, glade you liked it!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, normally I would do it with DOM, but in this special case I need to parse HTML-Code given from a WYSIWYG-Editor whish filters style-attributes. In general this is good, but for the pictures I would like to keep the set sizes with this html.replace-Hack.

This is the answer:

```
html = html.replace(/ style=".*?width:\s?(\d+).*?height:\s?(\d+).*?"/g, " width=\"$1\" height=\"$2\"");
```

Thanks for your help :-)